# In Spring MVC, what is the relationship between the objects involved in bean deserialization and validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring MVC via Spring Boot 1.2 and trying to get my arms around how request bodies are bound to domain model beans in my container. Here's my rough understanding so far:

- `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` takes `@RequestMapping`-annotated methods of my `@Controller`s and makes them available for requests that arrive at the `DispatchServlet`.
- Depending on the methods' parameter types and annotations, the  `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` handles injecting the necessary arguments into these methods.
- The `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is equipped with a `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to handle processing request and response bodies, which in turn has the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which in turn has the Jackson `ObjectBinder` that performs that actual deserialization/serialization to and from my domain objects.

But I'm confused about the role of these objects and the objects described in [Chapter 7 of the Spring documentation: "Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation). **Specifically, I don't understand exactly how the `DataBinder` and `BindingResult` play with the Jackson `ObjectMapper` and its results**.

For example, suppose I have the the following `@RestController` method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public MyBean postMyBean(@RequestBody @Valid MyBean myBean, BindingResult result) {
    return myBean;
}
```

- Because of `@RequestBody`, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is used to turn the request body a `MyBean` object. If this fails due to, say, unknown fields in the JSON string, will the `BindingResult` have this information?
- What data binding process, if not the JSON->Bean data binding, is reported with `BindingResult`?
- How does `DataBinder` factor into all of this?
- Are `DataBinder` and `BindingResult` orthogonal to using JSR-303?

Comment: Found this on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller: "An `@RequestBody` method parameter can be annotated with `@Valid`, in which case it will be validated using the configured Validator instance. When using the MVC namespace or the MVC Java config, a JSR-303 validator is configured automatically assuming a JSR-303 implementation is available on the classpath."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Q**: Because of `@RequestBody`, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is used to turn the request body a MyBean object. If this fails due to, say, unknown fields in the JSON string, will the `BindingResult` have this information?
- **A:** No, if converter throws an exception, that will propagate back as a 4xx error back to the user. First the JSON is converted using the converter then the binder/validator is used to validate the converted bean.

---

- **Q**: What data binding process, if not the JSON->Bean data binding, is reported with `BindingResult`?
- **A**: `BindingResult` holds the result of validations. If you have annotated your bean with `@Valid` followed by having a `BindingResult` as a method parameter, then the bean will be validated using JSR 303 based validator or using any custom validator for the bean that you may have registered.

---

- **Q**: How does DataBinder factor into all of this?
- **A:** Databinder is used for binding and validating beans (and for registering binders and validators). It is somewhat less important for binding `@RequestBody` annotated methods, where converters come into play instead, but it is used for validating past conversion.

---

- **Q**: Are `DataBinder` and `BindingResult` orthogonal to using JSR-303?
- **A:** No, JSR-303 validation happens through a `DataBinder` and the validation errors captured into a `BindingResult`.

Comment: Thank you. So in terms of binding with `@RequestBody`, `Converter`s and `DataBinder` are orthogonal, because the the `DataBinder` only performs validation, whereas binding occurs in the `Converter`?

Comment: Yes, that is a fair point - Converters and Databinders can be considered orthogonal specifically for a `@RequestBody` case